# x64dbg & Ghidra change combobox properties app in Visual C++ MFC

Tags: c++, mfc, api-reversing

Hello in the program code the property combobox is changed from enable to disable I would like to change that the program does not change this property. I have found commands that assign new items to combobox then the code suddenly enters the user32.dll module and after exiting it the property is changed. I think some value is passed to this user32.dll that defines the property change. Could someone please guide me on how to find the piece of code responsible for the property change? The program is written in Visual C++ MFC. I used x64dbg and Ghidra.

Comment: Hi and welcome to RE.SE. You simply want to enable a disabled window/control? Now if the program is naive enough to rely on this, you can simply find the window and use the `EnableWindow` function ... UIPI may interfere, so make sure to run at a high enough integrity level. [docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enablewindow)

Comment: Oh thanks for help, ye before EnableWindow was bool to enable and disable control.